# Simple Circuit analysis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

[image: Simple Circuit]

Someone could explain to me why $U_{in} = \varepsilon \frac{R_1}{(R_1+R_2)} $?

Comment: where is the reference point? The potential at a point only makes sense relative to a reference. You can also take $U_{in}$ to be zero.

Comment: The expression that you have written is wrong. See the units!

Comment: Looks like the ground is the anode of the battery, so $U_\text{in}$ is the voltage drop across the $R_1$ resistor

Comment: That's called a voltage divider.

Answer (score 1):

The voltage drop across each resistor is proportional to its resistance. To see this, first observe that the current through both resistors is the same. The proportionality comes from Ohm's Law.

To finish the problem, note that $U_\text{in}$ is equal to the voltage drop across $R_1$.